# drush sql-dump with --gzip from remote to local machine

Tags: drush

I can use drush sql-dump to get the production db from my remote server and save it to my local machine no problem using:

> drush @site-live sql-dump > /home/backups/my_db_backup.sql

but i want to enable the --gzip option to make the process faster which i've tried with

> drush @site-live sql-dump --gzip > /home/backups/my_db_backup.sql.gz

but i get this error from archive manager in Ubuntu:

> gzip: /home/backups/my_db_backup.sql.gz: not in gzip format

For starters...can i actually use --gzip with sql-dump?

UPDATE: the problem appears to be that "stdin: is not a tty" is being appended to the first line of the file whether it is a plain .sql or a .sql.gz file

Comment: Which PHP version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i managed to solve this, the first thread in [this question](http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/stdin-not-tty-4732.html) made me check my centos server to see if the mesg y was still in any of the bashrc files and i found the culprit in /etc/bashrc on my centos box. I was logging in from a terminal to whm from Ubuntu (whether Ubuntu made a difference i'm unsure).

Answer (score 0):

Here are few checks you should do:

- make sure that your gzip program is in your $PATH (just check if you've `gzip` command),
- disable any drush verbose messages to avoid printing any extra lines from  terminal which could break the compression,
- temporary use `-vd` to check how the command look like (`Executing` or `Backend invoke`) and make sure you've `--gzip` in your argument list, if it's not - you're getting the plain version of it for some reason (so you can redirect to `.sql` file instead)

If your `--gzip` is not invoked, even you're specifying one and `gzip` is configured correctly, then it's probably a drush bug. I think this could depend on PHP version which you're using as I've the same problem with PHP 5.5.

Answer (score 0):

From a quick search this seems to be a ubuntu(debian?)-specific issue, as it doesn't by default open a tty for a remote ssh session (your command worked fine for me on CentOS).  Try adding `--tty` as an ssh option to your drush command.

Maybe of use: https://www.drupal.org/node/1783330

Comment: thanks for this but this is what gets written to the .sql file when adding --tty: stdin: is not a tty
Unknown option: --tty.  See `drush help sql-dump` for available[error] options. To suppress this error, add the option --strict=0.